# Continuity of the Gauss Hypergeometric function

Tags: real-analysis, hypergeometric-function

I am studying the following hypergeometric function $G(x)=_2F_1(a,b,c;-|x|^2)$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n.$ According to this [post](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2), the hypergeometric function is analytic everywhere except on possible branch points $0,1,\infty$.

Does this imply that the function $G$ is continuous everywhere except when $x=0$ or $|x|^2=1?$

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to extract the analytic continuation from the integral representation, and the integrand function in such representation is continuous, well, you have continuity also over the region $|x|>1$. For instance $\text{Li}_2(z)$ is defined over $\{z\in\mathbb{R}:|z|\leq 1\}$ as $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n^2}=\int_{z}^{0}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt, $$
but if you take a suitable branch of the complex logarithm and consider
$$\text{PV}\int_{z}^{0}\frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt $$
you have an analytic continuation to the complex plane. *Analytic* implies *continuous*, in particular.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just found this post https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2 which under section 15.2(ii) says that the function is analytic, however I am not sure how to apply this to the real case